# Append multiple lists in a for loop | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
N1_0 = []
M1_0 = []

N1_1 = []
M1_1 = []

N1_2 = []
M1_2 = []

N1_4 = []
M1_4 = []

N1_6 = []
M1_6 = []

X = [0,1,2,4,6]

for M in np.arange(0,1,0.2):
    M2.append(float(M))
    N2.append(N(float(M)))

for x in X:
    for i in np.arange(0,5,1):
        N1_x.append(N2[i]/math.sqrt(x+1))
```

In the second for loop, I want to append N1_x for the values of x. I mean when x=0, the N1_0 list should be appended, when x=1 the Nx_1 list should be appended, and so on. I tried this way, but it is giving an error, I assume variables don't work this way in python. How should I go about it? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Put your lists into a collection (e.g. dictionary) not a bunch of separate variables.

Comment: It's a bit frowned upon, but you could use globals() and access the lists through a f-string

Comment: @Blupper Yes you could, but it is frowned upon for good reason.

Comment: @alani can you please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, the point is that although there are ways and means of achieving exactly what you ask for in terms of appending to these lists, it is a pointless exercise because you will have similar problems when you then need to access them. If you organise your data in a collection (e.g. dictionary) then you have a straightforward way to work with it throughout. Really `globals` is provided for specialist uses e.g. writing debuggers, and if "ordinary" code requires it then it suggests that the data is organised wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eval()`, here's the example.

`eval('x = 5')` is simply declaring a variable `x` with a value of 5, meaning, Python will execute the string inside `eval()` as a python command.

Then, here's the solution. The `{}` will be replaced by the value of `x`, then the whole line will be executed as the python command.

```
for x in X:
    for i in np.arange(0,5,1):
        eval('N1_{}.append(N2[i]/math.sqrt(x+1))'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The convenient way to organise your data will be via a dictionary.

You can start by initialising it to an empty dictionary:

```
N1 = {}
```

Then wherever you are currently accessing for example `N1_1` you would use instead `N1[1]`.

With your problematic access to `N1_x` in your inner loop (which would not work), you just change it to use `N1[x]` instead:

```
        N1[x].append(N2[i]/math.sqrt(x+1))
```

Another advantage is that with your initialisations such as:

```
N1_0 = []
N1_1 = []
...
```

although you could hard-code them simiarly as:

```
N1[0] = []
N1[1] = []
...
```

in fact you can do these with a single statement inside your outer loop over `x`:

```
for x in X:
    N1[x] = []
```

Comment: Sorry. But I'm even more confused. Can you explain your last statement "in fact you can......", is it a standalone thing or in relation to the empty dictionary method explained above.

Comment: Hey, I have 1 doubt..how do I call N1[0][i], that is, I want to call ith element from the N1[0]. This doesn't seem to be the right way N1[0][i].

Comment: @Kartik Yes, you can do that. `N1[0]` will be a list contained in the dictionary, and then `N1[0][i]` will be an element of that list. It is similar syntax for indexing lists as for extracting elements from dictionaries.